# Where do I look for the source of PHP's built-in crypt, as used in bcrypt password hashing?

Tags: php, cryptography

In this highly-praised [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/903600) to the question [*How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4795385/903600), the code delegates the cryptographic calculation to the `crypt` function.

According to the [original definition of bcrypt password hashing](http://static.usenix.org/event/usenix99/provos/provos.pdf), three 64-bit blocks derived from the constant `"OrpheanBeholderScryDoubt"` should be Blowfish-encrypted 64 times. I would like to check that portion of the source code, in PHP sources if that's in there, or wherever PHP delegates; that's in order to improve this [answer I made](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/3032/555), and [wikipedia's bcrypt entry as I read it now](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Bcrypt&oldid=499138394).

Where should I look for the source code of PHP's built-in `crypt`, and specifically the part used in bcrypt password hashing?

Comment: have a look at [PHPass implementation](https://github.com/rchouinard/phpass/blob/master/library/Phpass/Hash/Adapter/Bcrypt.php) and here's a [simpler implementation](https://gist.github.com/1053158) and here's the [crypt.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/crypt.c) from PHP-SRC

Comment: @AdnanShammout: thanks, but my question is _not_ about bcrypt in PHP; it is about the source of PHP's built-in crypt, as often used in bcrypt in PHP. I'll clarify the title of my question.

Comment: I have updated my comment, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @AdnanShammout: thanks, your later link looks very useful. Now I need to follow that and find where `php_crypt_blowfish_rn` lives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the following links would be helpful

- `crypt.c` from [PHP-SRC](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/crypt.c)
- `php_crypt_blowfish_rn` in `crypt_blowfish.c` from [PHP-SRC](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/crypt_blowfish.c#L819)